# Google Cloud Bigquery: logging/user/RESTful_api_key_empty [SUM]

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

We've received this alert several times, but could not find what caused the error. Does anyone occur this before? What is it?

```
**Policy**
[ALERT] API Missing more than 10 key
**Condition**
logging/user/RESTful_api_key_empty [SUM]
**Metric**
logging.googleapis.com/user/RESTful_api_key_empty
```

Comment: Could you give more details about your question by sharing the documents you are following and elaborating more on your requirements?